# Detect if a forloop has zero loops

Tags: sourcery

I'm trying to handle a case where a `forloop` with a `where` clause results in zero loops.

I've tried using `set` and `map` in various ways unsuccessfully, possibly one of those is the solution but I just couldn't get it right.

```
{% for variable in type.allVariables where variable.type.implements["SomeProtocol"]["name"] == "SomeProtocol" %}
// Add code for each variable
{% endfor %}
// Add backup code if forloop didn't do a single loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the stencil documentation of all places - who knew!

The for tag can take an optional {% empty %} block that will be displayed if the given list is empty or could not be found.

```
{% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>There are no users.</li>
{% endfor %}
```